# Possible to create a link in an Excel cell surrounded by other text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, hyperlink

Is it possible in Excel (2010) to create a hyperlink for a specific word in a cell that is surrounded by other text (as in, the link won't be the only thing in the cell).

I have noticed you can do something like:

```
=hyperlink(http://www.example.com/, Example Site)
```

...but obviously that only works when it's the only thing in the the cell.

I have tried highlighting the word or putting my cursor on it, but whenever I have the cell "active" the "hyperlink" option on the *insert* menu gets "grayed out".

Can this be done at all and if so, how?

Comment: as far as my knowledge of excel goes, it it not possible to create link to only a part of the textual content of a cell. Perhaps, one of the reasons for this is because excel is designed to select cells upon the clicks. Hence, a link on an entire cell is the only thing supported